# Retrieving individual resources that have legacy UUIDs in Eve

Tags: mongodb, flask, eve

I have a MongoDB collection with legacy UUID _id fields.

I can retrieve individual objects with pymongo by passing UUID objects:

```
from uuid import UUID
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client[DB_NAME]
collection = db[COLLECTION_NAME]

one_ok = collection.find_one(
    filter={'_id': UUID('eedacde6-e241-4f37-a57d-c4e8eb6601a7')})
one_not_ok = collection.find_one(
    filter={'_id': 'eedacde6-e241-4f37-a57d-c4e8eb6601a7'})

print(one_ok is None)  # prints False
print(one_not_ok is None)  # prints True
```

However I can't seem to get individual resources using Eve. I get a 404 for:

```
http://localhost:5000/collection1/eedacde6-e241-4f37-a57d-c4e8eb6601b7
```

The list returned by `http://localhost:5000/collection1` mentions a link `collection1/eedacde6-e241-4f37-a57d-c4e8eb6601b7` that seems to match the URL that returns a 404:

```
<resource href="collection1" title="collection1">
    <link rel="parent" href="/" title="home"/>
    <_meta>
    <max_results>25</max_results>
    <page>1</page>
    <total>2</total>
    </_meta>
    <resource href="collection1/eedacde6-e241-4f37-a57d-c4e8eb6601b7" title="Collection1">
        <_created>Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT</_created>
        <_etag>9718572fe2d17b12358691602f6bd5f1ee345b06</_etag>
        <_id>eedacde6-e241-4f37-a57d-c4e8eb6601b7</_id>
        <_updated>Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT</_updated>
    </resource>
    <resource href="collection1/98c67ae6-ee7b-4bd3-9ec1-56b70fa2a9c7" title="Collection1">
        <_created>Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT</_created>
        <_etag>75c2451d19750e1007274315672bf893f9654273</_etag>
        <_id>98c67ae6-ee7b-4bd3-9ec1-56b70fa2a9c7</_id>
        <_updated>Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT</_updated>
    </resource>
</resource>
```

This is my DOMAIN variable in settings.py. I set it up that way after following http://python-eve.org/tutorials/custom_idfields.html .

```
DOMAIN = {
    'collection1': {
        'item_url': 'regex("[a-f0-9]{8}-?[a-f0-9]{4}-?4[a-f0-9]{3}-?[89ab][a-f0-9]{3}-?[a-f0-9]{12}")',
        'schema': {
            '_id': {'type': 'uuid'},
        },
    }
}
```

I suspect this doesn't work because the UUIDs are 'Legacy UUIDs', but I might be wrong.

Any ideas on how I can make URL such as `http://localhost:5000/collection1/eedacde6-e241-4f37-a57d-c4e8eb6601b7` return individual resources?

### Workaround: hack Eve

I am able to make it work by hacking Eve. The code below must be added for each HTTP verb (GET, POST, etc).

In `eve/methods/get.py`

```
def getitem_internal(resource, **lookup):
    """
    <...>
    """
    req = parse_request(resource)
    resource_def = config.DOMAIN[resource]
    embedded_fields = resolve_embedded_fields(resource, req)

    #### hack ###
    if '_id' in lookup:
        if 'schema' in resource_def and '_id' in resource_def['schema']:
            if resource_def['schema']['_id'].get('type') == 'uuid':
                lookup['_id'] = UUID(lookup['_id'])
    #### end of hack ###

    soft_delete_enabled = config.DOMAIN[resource]['soft_delete']
    if soft_delete_enabled:
        # GET requests should always fetch soft deleted documents from the db
        # They are handled and included in 404 responses below.
        req.show_deleted = True

    document = app.data.find_one(resource, req, **lookup)
    <...>
```

Comment: Look in the mongo shell. These would either be recorded like `BinData(3,....)` or `BinData(4,....)`, "Legacy" should be `3`, and if acutally see Hex characters ( and not the `BinData` and base64 encoded output ) then it's stored as a string instead.

Comment: Yes `_id` fields are Legacy UUIDs: `BinData(3,"7trN5uJBTzelfcT...`

Comment: Can you get base64 encoded data from your python `UUID` object? I know there's a helper in the mongo shell, but before I go looking at documentation maybe you can. If you can, then you can get a `BinData` helper from pymongo. And I hope you follow the conclusion of where that goes.

Comment: Yes I can get the base64 value, but I am unsure how I can use it with Eve.